# How does torch.flatten() order the elements from the flattened dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 4D tensor of shape `[32,64,64,3]` which corresponds to `[batch, timeframes, frequency_bins, features]` and I do `tensor.flatten(start_dim=2)` (in PyTorch). I understand the shape will then transform to `[32,64,64*3] --> [batch,timeframes,frequency_bins*features]` - but in terms of the actual ordering of the elements within that new flattened dimension of `64*3` are the first 64 indexes relating to what would have been `[:,:,:,0]` the second 64 `[:,:,:,1]` and the final 64 `[:,:,:,2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of understanding, let us first take the simplest case where we have a tensor of rank 2, i.e., a regular matrix. PyTorch performs flattening in what is called [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), traversing from the "innermost" axis to the "outermost" axis.

Taking a simple 3x3 array of rank 2, let us call it `A[3, 3]`:

```
[[a, b, c],
 [d, e, f],
 [g, h, i]]
```

Flattening this from innermost to outermost axes would give you `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]`. Let us call this flattened array `B[3]`.

The relation between corresponding elements in `A` (at index `[i, j]`) and `B` (at index `k`) can easily be derived as:

```
k = A.size[1] * i + j
```

This is because to reach the element at `[i, j]`, we first move `i` rows down, counting `A.size[1]` (i.e., the width of the array) elements for each row. Once we reach row `i`, we need to get to column `j`, thus we add `j` to obtain the index in the flattened array.

For example, element `e` is at index `[1, 1]` in `A`. In `B`, it would occupy the index `3 * 1 + 1 = 4`, as expected.

Let us extend that same idea to a tensor of rank of rank 4, as in your case, where we are flattening only the last two axes.

Again, taking a simple rank 4 tensor `A` of shape `(2, 2, 2, 2)` as below:

```
A =
[[[[ 1,  2],
   [ 3,  4]],

   [[ 5,  6],
   [ 7,  8]]],


   [[[ 9, 10],
   [11, 12]],

   [[13, 14],
   [15, 16]]]]
```

Let us find a relation between the indices of `A` and `torch.flatten(A, start_dim=2)` (let's call the flattened version `B`).

```
B =
[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

  [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15]]]
```

Element 12 is at index `[1, 1, 0, 0]` in `A` and index `[1, 1, 0]` in `B`. Note that the indices at axes 0 and 1, i.e., `[1, 1]` remain intact even after partial flattening. This is because those axes are not flattened and thus not impacted.

This is fantastic! Thus, we can represent the transformation from `A` to `B` as

```
B[i, j, _] = A[i, j, _, _]
```

Our task now reduces to finding a relation between the last axis of `B` and the last 2 axes of `A`. But `A[i, j, _, _]` is a 2x2 array, for which we have already derived the relation `k = A.size[1] * i + j`,

`A.size[1]` would now change to `A.size[3]` as 3 is now the last axis. But the general relation remains.

Filling in the blanks, we get the relation between corresponding elements in `A` and `B` as:

```
B[i, j, k] = A[i, j, m, n]
```

where `k = A.size[3] * m + n`.

We can verify that this is correct. Element 14 is at `[1, 1, 1, 0]` in `A`. and moves to `[1, 1, 2 * 1 + 0] = [1, 1, 2]` in `B`.

*EDIT:* Added example

Taking @Molem7b5's example of array `A` with shape `(1, 4, 4, 3)`, from the comments:

Iterating from inner (`dim=3`) to outer axes (`dim=2`) of `A` gives consecutive elements of `B`. What I mean by this is:

```
// Using relation: A[:, :, i, j] == B[:, :, 3 * i + j]

// i = 0, all j
A[:, :, 0, 0] == B[:, :, 0]
A[:, :, 0, 1] == B[:, :, 1]
A[:, :, 0, 2] == B[:, :, 2]
// (Note the consecutive order in B.)

// i = 1, all j
A[:, :, 1, 0] == B[:, :, 3]
A[:, :, 1, 1] == B[:, :, 4]

// and so on until

A[:, :, 3, 2] == B[:, :, 11]
```

This should give you a better picture as to how the flattening occurs. When in doubt, extrapolate from the relation.

Comment: But if we have `A[1,4,4,3]` and we do 
`A[:,:,:,0] = 1`
`A[:,:,:,1] = 2`
`A[:,:,:,2] = 3`
Then `A[:,:,:,0] =  
tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]])`

If we then do `B = A.flatten(start_dim=2)`
`B[:,:,:4] = tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 1],
         [1, 2, 3, 1],
         [1, 2, 3, 1],
         [1, 2, 3, 1]]])`

So `A[:,:,:,0] != B[:,:,:4]`

Is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @Molem7b5 I have made the correction and used your example of `A[1, 4, 4, 3]`. You can verify that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct, the order of the data remains (as does the underlying memory layout too). Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(1, 1, 12, 3)

>>> x
tensor([[[[0.9942, 0.1458, 0.7069],
          [0.2749, 0.9886, 0.3127],
          [0.8236, 0.9903, 0.0779],
          [0.0385, 0.2587, 0.7001],
          [0.1113, 0.8011, 0.0176],
          [0.1597, 0.1456, 0.4040],
          [0.2168, 0.6588, 0.7472],
          [0.1607, 0.6133, 0.0700],
          [0.6749, 0.2120, 0.4192],
          [0.8809, 0.8893, 0.4950],
          [0.1695, 0.3175, 0.6653],
          [0.7216, 0.5403, 0.8244]]]])

>>> x.flatten()
tensor([0.9942, 0.1458, 0.7069, 0.2749, 0.9886, 0.3127, 0.8236, 0.9903, 0.0779,
        0.0385, 0.2587, 0.7001, 0.1113, 0.8011, 0.0176, 0.1597, 0.1456, 0.4040,
        0.2168, 0.6588, 0.7472, 0.1607, 0.6133, 0.0700, 0.6749, 0.2120, 0.4192,
        0.8809, 0.8893, 0.4950, 0.1695, 0.3175, 0.6653, 0.7216, 0.5403, 0.8244]))
```